# Player character wont collide with any of the object even though they all have a collider, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, collision

I have tried every way to fix this problem and nothing has worked.
Yes my character has a rigid body.
I have already checked if the box `IsTrigger` is not checked.
I am using a character controller.
The fallowing is the code I have for collision. Can anyone help to solve why it isn't colliding with anything?

```cs
public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Court")
        {
            Debug.Log("We hit the court");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say not colliding, do you meant its not triggering the code above? If you want that code to run then you need a collider on the object with the 'IsTrigger' checked.

Comment: @IstalriSkolir Yes when I collide with the object that has that tag it just goes through it. I tried the IsTrigger but it still goes through it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set up a collision matrix and your colliders have correct layers to be able to collide.

[image]

Comment: I checked that and it looks like everything is working